# TinyMCE image upload & insert without a gallery

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload, plugins, tinymce

I've been searching for a plugin of TinyMCE that allows to upload and insert an image in the text, the problem I've found with many plugins is allowing to see and select from a gallery of images of the server, that's a functionality I don't need or want, just allow the user to select an image from his computer, upload and insert it.

There is a plugin that acomplishes only this?

Thanks

Comment: So, what did you end up using?

Answer (score 1):

jbimages is what you might looking for.
Easy to integrate and to configure.
Just pups up the file uploader and places the image wherever you have your cursor in a post.
Just do not forget to set after installations the config files to 600 or 400.
You can find how-to 
http://pastebin.com/

Comment: there are nothing in your link

Answer (score -2):

TinyMCE does this as standard:
try http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/external_image_list_url